# Error message when attempting to convert Landuse polygon to Raster in QGIS 2.18.14

Tags: qgis, rasterization

I may be doing something obviously wrong, but I'm trying to convert a landuse polygon to a raster file for later use in QGIS 2.18.14. I've used the Rasterize function within QGIS succesfully previously but for this file I'm getting the following error message

`'ERROR 6: One and only one of -3d, -burn or -a is required.'`

Any ideas as to what may be going wrong?

Comment: what is your input command ? the error message is quite clear, you used 0, 2 or more parameters from this list (-3d, -burn, -a).

Comment: Tengo el mimo problema. Cree nuevo campo pero no los lee.

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange! As a new user, please [take the Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). Note: we have a focused Q&A format, and it looks like your message is a comment that you are experiencing the same problem. Once you earn more [reputation, you can comment on other people's posts](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), such as to ask clarifying questions about what the poster tried already.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/148195)

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what the `-3D`, `-burn` or `-a` are supposed to mean. But I encountered the same problem (same error message) when I tried to convert a polygon layer to raster. My uninformed guess is that it seems to have something to do with the "Attribute field" option in the "Rasterize (vector to raster)" window.

I was able to get around it when  I added a new "Attribute field" to the polygon layer that had a numeric value, and could select it as "Attribute field".

Without this new field I cannot select any Attribute field (the others were text), and the error is persistent.

Maybe this information can help to shed some light on the error message in your case.

Answer (score 1):

The QGIS rasterize tool is a GUI for the gdal_rasterize tool ([instructions here](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html))

-burn, -a, and -3d are all commands associated with the underlying tool as so:

- -burn value: A fixed value to burn into a band for all objects. A list of -burn options can be supplied, one per band being written to.
- -a attribute_name: Identifies an attribute field on the features to be used for a burn-in value. The value will be burned into all output
  bands.
- -3d: Indicates that a burn value should be extracted from the "Z" values of the feature. As of now, only points and lines are drawn in
  3D.

Given you're creating a raster from a landuse polygon using the QGIS GUI tool your error probably indicates that it can't read the attribute field that you've provided.

Try recreating the attribute field for the polygon, ensuring that nothing funny has happened to the field type

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I tried to convert a layer which was added as a "delimited text layer" in QGIS. The problem was solved when I saved the layer as an ESRI Shapefile.

If this is the case, right click on your layer and then: Save As>ESRI Shapefile.

Now try "Rasterize" with the shapefile you just created, as input.